# Rails Application fails with 500 for any page on Home Controller - Heroku Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having troubles figuring out what is wrong for this. My app is working perfectly in development on cloud9, but my production app on Heroku is not working. Any page I try to load from HomeController throws up the 500 error, so I imagine it has something to do with a before action for that controller, but I removed it and still get the error.
I have run `bundle install`, I have run `rake db:migrate`. 
I'm not really sure what else I am missing. Here is my code for the HomeController. When I visit a page linked to an action on my "ProductController" everything works fine, no error.

**EDIT**

Removed my code because it wasn't related in the end.

Comment: What does `heroku logs` print?, optionally you can add `-n` with the number of lines to show, max. 1.500.

Comment: Nothing useful. Just 500 error

Comment: What about the rails `production.log` file?

Comment: It is Heroku, no log files

Comment: When you make the push?

Comment: No issues when I make the push. It is only when I try to visit a view in the HomeController

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot migrations, which can explain why it fails everywhere.
Run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If it doesn't change, check the logs while refreshing the page:

```
heroku logs -t
```

You'll see the error.
Other explanation: you forgot to add API keys in the env variables on heroku.

Comment: I've done those things. It doesn't fail everywhere, only for HomeController actions.

Comment: Did you add your Shopify API keys ?

Comment: I did, but it turns out I copied over an environment variable incorrectly on my env variables. Thanks for posing the simple answer. I ran 'heroku config' to list my env variables and saw that one wasn't saved correctly

Comment: turns out this isn't the problem. It still is not working.